# bash command/script to delete older files version

Tags: linux, bash

I have 1 directory with a lot of pdf files. 
This files are generated by another script that renames files with a progressive number for new version: (example)

```
newyork_v1.pdf
newyork_v2.pdf
newyork_v3.pdf
miami_v1.pdf
miami_v2.pdf
rome_v1.pdf
```

The version number is relative to the file, some files are a version 1, someone at version 2 etc like in example.
Some files stay in version 1 for all own life, some files may grow to 10th version.

After copying this directory in a temp directory I'd like to delete old version for all files, in the example must remain:

```
newyork_v3.pdf
miami_v2.pdf
rome_v1.pdf
```

I try sort and delete by ls and sort command but I do not get the desired result, i try:

```
ls | sort -k2 -t_ -n -r | tail -n +2 | xargs rm
```

with this command stay only rome_v1.pdf

command or script are indifferent, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for file in $(ls *.pdf | awk -F'_' '{print $1}' | sort -u)
do
    count=$(ls ${file}* | wc -l)
    if [ ${count} -gt 1 ]; then
        ls -rv ${file}* | tail -$(($count-1)) | xargs rm
    fi
done
```

Comment: Just some improvements to the answer:
First using the modification date for sorting might fail. Just use the default sort order of `ls`.
Second use `ls -1` instead of `ls -l` it saves you the `awk` pipe

Comment: @Mojooo - I am not getting expected output with `ls -1`

Comment: @Amit It should give the correct output with `ls -1r | tail ...` or `ls -1 | head ...`

Comment: @Amit Just looked at the answer from Tim. The `-v` option should also be added to the ls command, because it can still fail if the version reaches 10 or higher (test with rome_v1.pdf, rome_v2.pdf, rome_v10.pdf)

Comment: I'm trying your script with the real data, I'm sorry but in example I don't explain well the files names. I have one file named 141_v1.pdf and other file 141A_v1.pdf. The file are different but in this case the script don't work and delete 141A_v1.pdf too. There is a solution? 
obviously remains valid as stated previously, between 141_v1.pdf and 141_v2.pdf the file that must be removed is 141_v1.pdf. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @user3375339 Between 141_v1.pdf and 141_v2.pdf, 141_v1.pdf will be removed. If you have 141A_v1.pdf, that too will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use GNU ls, you can try below:

```
for p in $(ls -v *.pdf | cut -d_ -f1 | sort | uniq); do
    ls -v $p* | head -n -1 | xargs -I{} rm {} 2>/dev/null
done
```

The -v flag of GNU ls sorts the files 'naturally' ie. in your case:

```
miami_v1.pdf
miami_v2.pdf
newyork_v1.pdf
newyork_v2.pdf
newyork_v3.pdf
newyork_v10.pdf #Added to show ls -v in action
rome_v1.pdf
```

We then loop through each uniq prefix and delete everything other than the last file which matches the prefix.

Result:

```
miami_v2.pdf
newyork_v10.pdf
rome_v1.pdf
```

Update:

Changed xargs to handle whitespace and special characters.

Answer (score 0):

This Perl script can be used to filter out the old file names:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %files;
my @old_files;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name, $version, undef) = split /_v|\./, $_;
    if (!$files{$name}->{version}) {
        $files{$name}->{version} = $version;
        $files{$name}->{name} = $_;
        next;
    }
    if ($files{$name}->{version} < $version) {
        push @old_files, $files{$name}->{name};
        $files{$name}->{version} = $version;
        $files{$name}->{name} = $_;
    }
}

foreach my $file (@old_files) {
    print "$file\n";
}

__DATA__
newyork_v1.pdf
newyork_v2.pdf
newyork_v3.pdf
miami_v1.pdf
miami_v2.pdf
rome_v1.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't install perl on this machine :(

Comment: @user3375339 Oh, that is unfortunate.